# Adicionar Chave Fornecida pela Google no meu APP

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

A Google Play sugere uma chave de licença para meu app

Eles tem uma chave pública RSA codificada na Base64 para incluir no seu arquivo binário. Remova eventuais espaços.

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9...
```

Como adiciono essa chave fornecida por eles no meu arquivo binário. Esse arquivo binário é o APK?

Comment: Sim o arquivo binário é o APK. Como colocar a licença, você poderá ler mais aqui: https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html

Comment: Você quer gerar um apk assinado com uma chave release certo?! Você usa eclipse ou android studio?

Comment: Android Studio. Gostaria de inserir a chave que o Google Fornece